# Netbeans debug node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` and `node --inspect-brk` instead

Tags: node.js, netbeans

Hello I am trying to debug a nodejs application with Netbeans.

I have try with both Netbeans 17 and Netbeans 18 but I get this error:

[DEP0062]: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` and `node --inspect-brk` instead.

I have try to put --inspect and --inspect-brk at the arguments of the run settings but it did not worked.

Any help is appreciated.